# FloatingActionButton doesn't start invisible

Tags: java, android, anchor, floating-action-button

I want to do a FAB which is opening 2 other FABs to left after clicking. But it doesn't start invisibled. I used all way in those codelines but It doesn't work. `(ScaleX-Y = 0, android:invisibility, setInvisibility etc..)`

**DersActivity.java**

```
private Boolean isFabOpen = false;
private FloatingActionButton fab_ders, fab_ders_ara, fab_ders_ekle;
private Animation fab_open, fab_close, rotate_forward, rotate_backward;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    ...
    fab_ders = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_ders);
    fab_ders_ara = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_ders_ara);
    fab_ders_ekle = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_ders_ekle);
    fab_open = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_open_ders);
    fab_close = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_close_ders);
    rotate_forward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate_forward);
    rotate_backward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate_backward);
    fab_ders.setOnClickListener(this);
    fab_ders_ara.setOnClickListener(this);
    fab_ders_ekle.setOnClickListener(this);
    ...
    ...
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.fab_ders:

            animateFAB();
            break;
        case R.id.fab_ders_ara:

            Log.d("Test", "Fab 1");
            break;
        case R.id.fab_ders_ekle:

            Log.d("Test", "Fab 2");
            break;
    }
}

public void animateFAB() {

    if (isFabOpen) {

        fab_ders.startAnimation(rotate_backward);
        fab_ders_ara.startAnimation(fab_close);
        fab_ders_ekle.startAnimation(fab_close);
        fab_ders_ara.setClickable(false);
        fab_ders_ekle.setClickable(false);
        isFabOpen = false;
        Log.d("Test", "close");

    } else {

        fab_ders.startAnimation(rotate_forward);
        fab_ders_ara.startAnimation(fab_open);
        fab_ders_ekle.startAnimation(fab_open);
        fab_ders_ara.setClickable(true);
        fab_ders_ekle.setClickable(true);
        isFabOpen = true;
        Log.d("Test", "open");

    }
}
```

I used `Animation` in this file but It doesn't matter to problem.

**activity_ders.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".DersActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

                <include layout="@layout/tool_bar2"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_ders"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_ders_ekle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab2_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_circle_white_24dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFAB2"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            android:scaleX="0.0"
            android:scaleY="0.0"
            android:alpha="0.0"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_ders_ara"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab1_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFAB2"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            android:scaleX="0.0"
            android:scaleY="0.0"
            android:alpha="0.0"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_ders"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFAB2"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/nav_view"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve visually:

[image]

[image]

Comment: `fab.setVisibiity(GONE)` - is there available?

Comment: Yes, I did but it does not work too.

Comment: try also `fab.hide()`

Comment: @piotrek1543  bro I used all ways but It does not work.

Comment: `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'`

`compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'`

Comment: at DersActivity.java in onCreate after setOnClickListener methods I used them but It does not work.

Comment: Because there are 3 FABS

[link](http://oi65.tinypic.com/jafmkj.jpg)

[link](http://oi66.tinypic.com/idheo1.jpg)

Comment: Ahh, ok.  Have you considered using a library to do this?  This is one library available for this kind of thing: https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton